Hide file URLs from users (Firebase Storage)
I am developing a web app on Javascript. There is one feature in which an image can be shown on screen. I have these images uploaded on Firebase Storage.
I have already done this but I don't want the users to see the URL of those images. The URL is not shown directly, but it can be seen if you inspect the code with F12 for example.
Here are my questions:

Is there any way to hide or to encrypt that URL?
Is there any problem if a user see the URL? The URL is something like https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[project name].appspot.com/o/[filename]?alt=media&token=[characters]. Is there any security problem if these URLs are shown?
If I can't achieve this, do you recommend any other storage in which I can access the files dynamically from code?

Thank you
I haven't found any solution to this and even I read it's not possible to do this but it wanted to share my problem here to see if there is any option.

If you want the browser to load and display the contents of the URL, then it can't possibly be hidden.  That URL will always be available for someone to intercept and use directly. Whether or not that's OK is up to you to figure out - we can't tell you what the requirements of your app should be.  You're going to have the same problem with any cloud storage product that gives you a URL for the client app to display that doesn't require authentication.

To avoid all this, your only viable option here is to build some backend middleware that check the credentials of the user to determine if they should have access to the underlying content.

@DougStevenson Thank you Doug!
I will find other alternatives then

As mentioned by Doug, this is not possible directly, as the URL is the source therefore it'll be visible, if you have a middleware layer then you can resolve it there, however then you will see the resolution to your middleware endpoint.
An alternative but not sure if that works for your usecase can be to use signed urls, but for that you will need a service that creates this nsigned URL which will be visible
